# how to make multiple subset in enum

Tags: c#, enums

I'm having troubles using enum as a flag.
This is the description :

[image]

This is my enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum AuthorityFlagsEnum : short
{
    Output_1_enable = 1 << 0,
    Output_2_enable = 1 << 1,
    Output_3_enable = 1 << 2,
    Output_4_enable = 1 << 3,

    Arm_Disarm = 1 << 4,
    Bypass_enable = 1 << 5,
    Open_Close_report_enable = 1 << 6,

    Arm_only = Output_2_enable,
    Arm_only_during_close_window = Output_3_enable,
    Master_Program = Output_4_enable,
}
```

How can I know in my method if the flags set are from the first set (arm only, master/program) or from the second set (output 1 - 4)?

Comment: What is the signature of your method? Does it take several byte parameters?

Comment: I think you should have two different sets of enums. One for when "bit 7 is clear" and a second one for when "bit 7 is set". Otherwise I don't think it's possible to magically know one from the other. EDIT: Another possibility is to give the `Arm_only` and associated values a unique value. Then when you read/write your bytes, have it convert to the correct bit value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't. In the end, `enum` is just a pretty integer. The underlying value of the `enum` will just be the number you specified. The `Enum` class provides functionality to convert an integer to an object of your `enum` type, and back, but it will get confused when you have duplicate numbers.

Really the only way to go is to have multiple `enum`'s if you need to differentiate between the values.

Comment: Ok, I'll go with the multiple enum approach.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you provided, it looks like you need to look at **bit 7**. I'd recommend including that last bit in your enum as a flag (and also change the type of the enum to byte) like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum AuthorityFlagsEnum : byte
{
    Output_1_enable = 1 << 0,
    Output_2_enable = 1 << 1,
    Output_3_enable = 1 << 2,
    Output_4_enable = 1 << 3,

    Arm_Disarm = 1 << 4,
    Bypass_enable = 1 << 5,
    Open_Close_report_enable = 1 << 6,
    SecondSet = 1 << 7,  // <--- Include a flag that indicates First/Second set

    Arm_only = Output_2_enable,
    Arm_only_during_close_window = Output_3_enable,
    Master_Program = Output_4_enable,
}
```

This would enable you to convert a byte directly to the enum value, and also know whether it is first or second set:

```
byte byte3 = 2; //00000010 --> SecondSet is False (FirstSet)
var authFlags = (AuthorityFlagsEnum)byte3;
if (authFlags.HasFlag(AuthorityFlagsEnum.SecondSet))
{
    //Second set: bit 2 is Output_2_enable
    if (authFlags.HasFlag(AuthorityFlagsEnum.Output_2_enable))
        //...
}
else
{
    //First set: bit 2 is Arm_only
    if (authFlags.HasFlag(AuthorityFlagsEnum.Arm_only))
        //...
}
```